# jQuery - How to brighten an image

Tags: jquery, css

Hi
In jQuery, we can use the code as below, to make the image darkly. In opposite, how can we bright up an image?

```
$(this).hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.5 }, 500);
},
function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use [Pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/) for this. It has [jQuery bindings](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/#jquery) if you want to take that route.

You can [lighten or darken an image](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/lighten/) like this:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    Pixastic.process(img, "lighten", {amount:0.5});
}
document.body.appendChild(img);
img.src = "myimage.jpg";
```

---

You could fake this effect by changing the opacity of the image, making sure that the background behind the image is white.